# using Xcode 10 for python, gets a launch error

Tags: python-3.x, xcode10, macos-mojave

I want to use Xcode to create python applications and I am testing it and every time I want to run the project I get the following error:

> There is a problem launching using posix_spawn (error code: 8).

And Xcode also said build succeeded.

what can I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: If you want an answer, you need to update your question with more detailed information on how you set up the project. What type of Xcode project did you create? What files did you add to the project? How do you set up the project to use the Python interpreter? What is your code that calls posix_spawn? How do you run the project? Keep in mind that Xcode is not a good IDE for developing Python programs. You would be better off using a text editor like Visual Studio Code, BBEdit, or TextMate to write your Python programs.

Comment: Ok thx,Actually I just wanted to post that I fixed it by reseting some Xcode features.

Comment: Add an answer with what you did to fix the error to help someone who has this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try change executable interpreter to /usr/bin/pythonw